# How to play avi files on browser

Tags: flash, video, ffmpeg, video.js, avi

My team needs to develop a system that plays avi files on the web. These files are recorded by a hardware whose firmware we don't have access to. We are trying to negotiate it with the manufacturer to change the file format to mp4, but until now we have nothing.

Because of this, we are trying another manners to make it work. Our first attempt was to use FFMPEG to convert the files to mp4 (or webm or ogg), but this process takes too long because we have to do it everyday with a really huge amount of videos.

We also tried to use FFMPEG's copy command (which is much faster), but the video always crashes at some point **(mainly when we need to navigate in its timeline)** and we don't know why.

So now we are thinking to customize videojs flash player to reproduce the AVI files, but because we don't have too much experience with video programming and flash, we don't know if this is possible. Is it possible to write a decoder in action script to read avi files?

I saw that Youtube and Facebook can play AVI files... How do they do this? I have already looked a lot about it, but had no success.

**EDIT 1**

*avi video file before copy command:*

```
$ ffmpeg -i video.avi
ffmpeg version N-82324-g872b358 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dx                                                                                                                                                                                               va2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-lib                                                                                                                                                                                               ebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --ena                                                                                                                                                                                               ble-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfree                                                                                                                                                                                               type --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enab                                                                                                                                                                                               le-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-lib                                                                                                                                                                                               openh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschr                                                                                                                                                                                               oedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheor                                                                                                                                                                                               a --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvo                                                                                                                                                                                               rbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --ena                                                                                                                                                                                               ble-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --e                                                                                                                                                                                               nable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 36.100 / 55. 36.100
  libavcodec     57. 66.101 / 57. 66.101
  libavformat    57. 57.100 / 57. 57.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 66.100 /  6. 66.100
  libswscale      4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, avi, from 'video.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         :
  Duration: 00:50:07.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p                                                                                                                                                                                               (progressive), 352x240, 3 fps, 3 tbr, 3 tbn, 6 tbc
At least one output file must be specified
```

*copy command (with no audio stream because the videos don't have it):*

```
$ ffmpeg -i video.avi -vcodec copy video.mp4
ffmpeg version N-82324-g872b358 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 36.100 / 55. 36.100
  libavcodec     57. 66.101 / 57. 66.101
  libavformat    57. 57.100 / 57. 57.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 66.100 /  6. 66.100
  libswscale      4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, avi, from 'video.avi':
  Metadata:
encoder         :
  Duration: 00:50:07.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(progressive), 352x240, 3 fps, 3 tbr, 3 tbn, 6 tbc
Output #0, mp4, to 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf57.57.100
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(progressive), 352x240, q=2-31, 3 fps, 3 tbr, 12288 tbn, 3 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 0000000002513fc0] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[NULL @ 0000000002524020] missing picture in access unit with size 16
Last message repeated 300 times
frame= 9324 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1388kB time=01:38:27.66 bitrate=   1.9kbits/s speed=3.32e+004x
video:1354kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.493988%
```

*mp4 video file after copy command:*

```
$ ffmpeg -i video.mp4
ffmpeg version N-82324-g872b358 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dx                                                                                                                                                                                               va2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-lib                                                                                                                                                                                               ebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --ena                                                                                                                                                                                               ble-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfree                                                                                                                                                                                               type --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enab                                                                                                                                                                                               le-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-lib                                                                                                                                                                                               openh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschr                                                                                                                                                                                               oedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheor                                                                                                                                                                                               a --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvo                                                                                                                                                                                               rbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --ena                                                                                                                                                                                               ble-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --e                                                                                                                                                                                               nable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 36.100 / 55. 36.100
  libavcodec     57. 66.101 / 57. 66.101
  libavformat    57. 57.100 / 57. 57.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 66.100 /  6. 66.100
  libswscale      4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf57.57.100
  Duration: 01:38:28.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yu                                                                                                                                                                                               v420p, 352x240, 1 kb/s, 1.58 fps, 3 tbr, 12288 tbn, 24576 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

**EDIT 2**

I uploaded two little samples if somebody wants to test:

- [AVI video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzL0rVo2lqfVczF1YVpJU0Y3bG8/view?usp=sharing); This one don't run on browser.
- [MP4 video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzL0rVo2lqfVMEtkMDJmajB5Nlk/view?usp=sharing). This one crashes at second 5.

Comment: You should show some info about the AVI files: `ffmpeg -i input.avi`. How can we reproduce the "video always crashes at some point and we don't know why" issue?

Comment: It depends on the codec. if its AVC/VP9, AAC/OOG then its possible to simply repackage (either server side, or in the browser. in the browser is WAY harder). If is a different codec, you have no choice but to transcode. Your best bet is to fix the ffmpeg crash.

Comment: Logs added, @LordNeckbeard! Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Well _"Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0..."_ explains your crash whenever you try to seek in some media player. Check if FFmpeg has a command to repair timestamps, check the docs if `genPTS` make sense...

Comment: Thanks, @VC.One! I'll take a look. Do you have some tip, @Mulvya?

Comment: A link to a short sample input file would be helpful.

Comment: Samples added, @LordNeckbeard.

Comment: @VC.One In the MP4 (and AVI),  H264 bitstream is malformed. ffplay shows following errors for both formats: `Frame num change from 5 to 6` `decode_slice_header error` and also `missing picture in access unit with size 16`. The timestamps msg is a warning by the muxer, not an error, that the incoming frame has no PTS. But the MP4 muxer will set it, so the output won't have that issue. When I wrap the video to TS, I get `H.264 bitstream error, startcode missing`. Typical of IP cameras. To the OP, you'll need a video stream parser or convertor by the manufacturer.

Comment: @Mulvya, I didn't get it very well. What does it mean? What is TS and OP? Do I can correct the problem with FFMPEG? Is the problem at the recording itself? Sorry, but all these information about videos and FFMPEG is too new for me and a little bit confusing.

Comment: The video stream format is unique to the manufacturer. ffmpeg cannot reliably read the video. You have to contact the hardware company to provide a software to correctly convert or rewrap the video.

Comment: Ok, @Mulvya! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally solved this problem.

Although the @VC.One's solution seems to work, we didn't made it because we thought there were a better way to solve it without have to make bytes operations (once we don't have to much experience with it)...

After a lot of tries, we realized our AVI file was malformed, so we used a program named Mencoder, which has the function *forceidx*:

> Force index rebuilding. Useful for files with broken index (A/V desync, etc). This will enable seeking in files where seeking was not possible. You can fix the index permanently with MEncoder (see the documentation).
>       NOTE: This option only works if the underlying media supports seeking (i.e. not with stdin, pipe, etc).

After run this command, we then used FFMPEG's copy command to "convert" the (now well formed) AVI file to mp4. Voilá! The magic happened!

Thanks a lot guys!

Thanks, @VC.One by your time dispended here!

Comment: Can you please add the `mencoder` command you used to fix the `.avi` file ??

Answer (score 6):

> We also tried to use FFMPEG's `copy` command (which is much faster), but
>   the video always crashes at some point (mainly when we need to
>   navigate in its timeline) and we don't know why.

Here is a link to your [**re-fixed MP4**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mrk9qtpnefajbgw/video_bytesEdit.mp4?dl=0). Seeking is now working.
 
I manually checked the bytes and, as I suspected, the timestamps were wrong.

FFprobe (using `ffprobe video.avi`) says AVI duration is 5.88 seconds. [**MPC-HC**](https://mpc-hc.org/) also showed duration as 6 seconds (rounded). Now we later expect the MP4 to also have same 5.88 duration when using `copy` command. But after `copy`, the output MP4 has a new 10 second duration???

An MP4 puts duration in 3 places. Each software has own rules of which entry to check so best to edit all 3 places for everybody's sake. The metadata is divided into "atoms" so we edit 3 atoms.

These atoms called `mvhd`, `tkhd`, and `elst` all had byte values `00 00 28 87` for duration, which equals 10375 ms (or 10.375 sec). 
This is wrong because we want 5880 ms (or 5.88 secs). I manually changed them all from `00 00 28 87` to become `00 00 16 F8` which gives 5880 millisecs. Now MPC-HC thinks the mp4 is 5 seconds (phew!!) but Chrome keeps saying it's still 10 seconds (damn!!).

As a last resort I checked an atom called `stts`. This had 3 items for timings of a total 136 frames (note FFprobe says AVI actually had 141 frames). Anyways the first item said the first 128 frames have a display time of 512 ms (which takes duration to `128 * 512 = 65536 ms`). This is wrong.

To cut a long story short. I edited the `stts` to say...

- Instead of `03` there is only `01` display time entry (yet other entry bytes were not deleted).
- Instead of `00 00 00 80` = 128, there is actually `00 00 00 8D` = 141 frames
- I still kept the original display time for these (now 141 frames) as `00 00 02 00` = 512 ms
- I changed the remaining two entries bytes all to zero's (since we don't need use them).

That's how your MP4 become a working seekable file as tested in Chrome browser.

**Conclusion :**

To fix your own files I suspect editing just the first entry only of `stts` section in MP4 metadata is enough. You're telling it *"I have X-amount of frames, each frame displays for X interval, no extras!!"*. Then just edit the duration times in `mvhd`, `tkhd`, `elst`. Here you must know how to work with bytes.

Write a desktop program that (if someone in your team can do it)...

- Gets "duration" and "total frames" from AVI (I recommend ExifTool over FFprobe cos it shows both details correctly). Your program reads this info via **std in/out**.
- Once known, search the atom names as **UTF** text to find their **beginning** positions within bytes.
- When you have each start position... you will now edit the numbers as 4-byte Integers (written in Hex notation)

  - find start pos of "`mvhd`" then skip 20 bytes to find duration.
  - find start pos of "`tkhd`" then skip 24 bytes to find duration.
  - find start pos of "`elst`" then skip 24 bytes to find duration.
- Finally find start pos of "`stts`" then skip 8 bytes to find total entries (4 bytes). After that the next 4 bytes are "total frames" number (you fix with real number), Then next following 4 bytes are timing for frames but leave that un-changed...

**Other Query :** ...

> Is it possible to write a decoder in action script to read avi files?
>   I saw that Youtube and Facebook can play AVI files... How do they do
>   this?

Yes!! Since your AVI has Mpeg (H.264) video, Flash has a decoder that accepts MPEG a/v bytes so if you extract frame bytes from AVI and feed them to decoder it will display.

This old [**demo app**](http://swfcabin.com/swf-files/1411416171.swf) is one example where I feed Mpeg's AAC audio bytes to the decoder. Same principle for your AVI. I work with Flash but I'll tell you... Better to fix the files than have a situation where only one customized app in the world can play them. A fixed file works in Flash, HTML5 browser and everywhere else.

PS : Facebook and Youtube are re-encoding your file. It's not a direct file copy.

Comment: *display time of 512 ms* - this is in timebase units, not ms. For a tbn of 12288, 512 represents 512/12288 s = 0.0416 s = 1/24 s.

Comment: This is amazing, @VC.One! We wil try it! I come back ASAP! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya ... Ahh timeBase!! Brain knows timeScale. Note: FFprobe says AVI has a `tbn = 24`. I wonder if the encoder is putting _`frame-rate`_ as if _`tbn`_ for AVI? Later that causes some issues when changing containers? Anyways as you noted... The codec (_h.264_) is partly corrupt, we see the header (_avi_) is not correctly filled, I don't get how they are licensed to encode H.264 video but somehow can't contain it within the offical MP4? PS: See [**this image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px3bo.png), it's from the MP4 metadata of the OP's unseekable MP4 video as linked. I'm confused ;-)

Comment: @mvalencaa you said the video is coming from external hardware, right? I mean, is it classed as a video capture device in your computer? If yes then maybe FFmpeg itself could capture & encode the MP4 via input from hardware...

Comment: Right, but the hardware is a DVR inside a vehicle and unfortunately we do not have access to its firmware. @VC.One